my quiz in php dos not stop at last array item
This code is giving med problem. It dos not stop when the last question has been answered. It just give me this error:
Warning: Undefined array key 2 in /customers/5/8/b/kbekker.dk/httpd.www/Fag/Dansk/Opgaver/Ordklasser/find_navneord_001.php on line 71 Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /customers/5/8/b/kbekker.dk/httpd.www/Fag/Dansk/Opgaver/Ordklasser/find_navneord_001.php on line 71 3

which is refering to line:
 <label for="question"><?php echo ($currentQuestion+1).". ". $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["question"];?></label>

I am a noob at php.
I have try to put a loop outside of it, but that dos not help either.
<?php
// Declare all your questions and answers as multi dimensional array
$questionsAndAnwsers = array(array("question" => "1. How many sides does a triangle have?", "answer" => "three"),
                            array("question" => "2. How many sides does a square have?", "answer" => "four"));
      
// current question
$currentQuestion = 0;
if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
    $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
    if($_POST["guess"] == $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["answer"]){
        // answer was correct, increment your question-counter for the next question
        $currentQuestion++;
        // print success message
        echo "Det var rigtigt";
    } else {
        // question was wrong, counter stays as it is, so same question will be printed
        // print failure message
        echo "prøv igen";
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="question"><?php echo ($currentQuestion+1).". ". $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["question"];?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="currentQuestion" value="<?php echo $currentQuestion;?>">
    <input type="text" name="guess" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>


You have nothing that checks if $currentQuestion is too high. Something like if ($currentQuestion >= count($questionsAndAnswers))

Since you are displaying each question standalone it is not feasable to use a for loop. You could use it, if all questions are displayed on the same page and the users answers them all at the same time, to then check the results. At the current state you have to check if all questions have been correctly answered by comparing the currentQuestionId and the length of questions.
We can check this by doing the following:
if ($currentQuestion >= count($questionsAndAnwsers)) {
   // Display questions
}
else {
   // Display quiz completion
}

You would then either print the form as you currently do, or on completion, display a message.
Here's a better version of the code given:
if ($currentQuestion >= count($questionsAndAnwsers)) {
    echo "Tillykke! Du har gennemført quizzen!"; 
} else {
    // current question
    $currentQuestion = 0;
    if(isset($_POST["currentQuestion"])){
        $currentQuestion = $_POST["currentQuestion"];
        if($_POST["guess"] == $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["answer"]){
            // answer was correct, increment your question-counter for the next question
            $currentQuestion++;
            // print success message
            echo "Det var rigtigt";
        } else {
            // question was wrong, counter stays as it is, so same question will be printed
            // print failure message
            echo "prøv igen";
        }
    }
    echo '
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label for="question">'.($currentQuestion + 1) . ". " . $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["question"].'</label><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="currentQuestion" value="<?php echo $currentQuestion; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="guess" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>';
}


Thank you, I did also have problem with how to put the form inside the php. So this is great. unfortunately I get this error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function len()", it referer to the line: if ($currentQuestion >= len($questionsAndAnwsers)){. So It does not show the quiz on the webpage. Can You help with this?

but if I use:  count($questionsAndAnwsers)) I get shown the quiz, but it does not respon to the correkt answer.

Yes, I've been using too much python and accidentally used len instead of count. You of course need to still check if the question is correct. I updated the answer to include your previous checks, if the answer is correct. This should now work
